# Compile java to object files compatible with C/C++

Tags: java, c++, c

So I am working(actually still planning) on a GUI project, and I need control over every single pixel on the window. I have done a lot of Java and I know how to do that, the problem is that I want to do all the logic on C++(because I just love how it works) and I don't even know how to  setup a GUI in C++(I already took a small look at Qt, but I haven't done anything great).
So I had this idea of writing all the GUI related things in Java and somehow compile java source files to object files that can be linked with the rest of C++ code. This is just a personal project I am working on so I don't care if I lose the cross-compatibility of Java.

Thanks to anyone who took time to read this.

Comment: You will most likely find this to be very painful to debug and maintain why it is important that you try doing it so you have tried 

Comment: I'll pop this down here, just another resource. It distinguishes between creating a C or C++ stub. Just additional information. You may have to scour a few resources to actually get it all set up. It is a multi step process; you're generating little stubs to include and .dll's (on Win) to drag along with your program. But you'll figure it out. I had fun using it. Go experiment and have fun, I enjoyed it on my project, it had a reason for being there too, it was 100 times faster and didn't stutter ... same lines of nested for loop and int code from the java method. Then, I never used jni again!

Comment: http://www.soulmachine.me/blog/2015/07/23/calling-c-code-from-java-using-jni/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into JNI. Years ago, when doing the game of life in programming class, I chose to have a C function do the pixel work, just like you are thinking of, because it, ahem, back then, made the graphics work run many times faster. Noticeably, back then anyway.

1. Write the Java Program and Compile
2. Generate header file from java class
3. Write the C Program
4. Generate Shared Library File
5. Run Java Program

[Here's one of probably many resources to show you.](https://javapapers.com/core-java/how-to-call-a-c-program-from-java/)